# Cucumber rescue Exception (Ruby/HTTParty)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, httparty

I'm just get a Exception while running a Cucumber test and I tried to find what I can do for it, but no luck about that.

When I made a post in the last step:

```
When('accept terms of use') do
  until @o == 200
  @o = CadastroApp.sign_term1.code
  sleep 1
  end
end

class CadastroApp
  include HTTParty
   def self.sign_term1
   post("#{$uat_uri}agree/multipleterms",
     body: {
       'ContractsId': $contract1,
       'deviceType': 'Smartphone',
       'Platform': 'ios',
       'Model': 'Iphone XS max',
     }.to_json,
     headers: {
       'Authorization': "Bearer #{$auth_token}",
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     })
   end
  end
```

I got the error:

```
52: def self.cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering(pseudo_method)
53:   begin
54:     yield
55:   rescue Exception => e
56:     instance_exec_invocation_line = "#{__FILE__}:#{__LINE__ - 2}:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'"
57:     replace_instance_exec_invocation_line!((e.backtrace || []), instance_exec_invocation_line, pseudo_method)
58:     raise e
59:   end
60: end
```

I don't know if it is a problem, but I was using a lot of "until @variable == 200" to loop the api until I got response code 200.

Comment: That isn't an error. Post the stack trace.

Comment: @anothermh how can I do this? I tried to put wtf command but just get "Error: No most-recent exception"

Comment: Ok, I using wtf command correctly, but got this "Error: No most-recent exception" response

Comment: Maybe the api are producing this rescue? Even with a 200 and ok msg

Comment: "I'm just get a Exception while running a Cucumber test" how do you know you got an exception if you don't see an exception?

Comment: I thought if I get a "rescue Exception" could be a Exception. I only see that because I used pry-nav to interrupt the loop. I just used Kubernetes to get the API log, and found a timeout when I get in this step. Maybe this can be the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a error. This is a response send by Ruby when I get a failure in the step.

Answer (score 0):

It was a MYSQL problem. When I request the API, MYSQL don't close the requisition, so I get a lot of timeouts when I check on Kubernetes.

```
Exception Caught by LogRequestResponseMiddleware:
1) ----- Exception Type
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
1) ----- Exception Source
MySql.Data
1) ----- Exception TargetSite
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver GetConnection()
1) ----- Exception Message
error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
Message = error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reac
hed.
```

So I republished the API and automation works fine.